# Shell script to extract certain fields from XML files

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I am new to the Linux shell and I can't understand regex's.

Here is my question:
I have a directory called `/var/visitors`
and under this directory, I have directories like `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`.
In each of these directories, there is a file called `list.xml`
and here, for example, is the content of `list.xml` from `/var/visitors/a`:

```
<key>Name</key>
<string>Mr Jones</string>
<key>ID</key>
<string>51</string>
<key>Len</key>
<string>53151334</string>
```

What I want to do is to merge the `Name` field with its corresponding string and merge the `ID` field with its corresponding string. I don't need any other fields.

```
Name: Mr Jones
ID: 51
---
Name: Ms Maggie
ID: 502
```

Here is what I how far I got:

```
cd /var/visitors
find -name "list.xml" | xargs grep ?????
```

Please help.

Comment: grep sounds like the wrong tool for this. Consider creating a XSLT for this

Comment: is not anybody capable of writing this in sed?

Answer (score 2):

Not elegant, but this will work:

```
find -name "list.xml" | xargs cat | tr -d "\n" | sed 's/<\/string>/\n/g' | sed 's/<\/key>/: /g' | sed 's/<[^>]*>//g' | egrep "Name:|ID:" | sed 's/Name: /---\nName: /g'
```

Basically it does this:

- remove all newlines
- put each key value pair on its own line
- add : separator
- remove all element content (between < and >)
- only save Name and ID fields (drop all others)
- add --- separator

Sample Output:

```
---
Name: Greg
ID: 52
---
Name: Amy
ID: 53
---
Name: Mr Jones
ID: 51
```

Answer (score 0):

Grep is not going to help you here, you are going to need to use something like sed or awk.

Comment: well my friend told me to use one of them. although i read the man pages, i couldn't come up with a solution :(

Comment: because it can't do it, I hope someone else can show you how to do it with sed or awk cause I'm busy now, if I get a break and no one has answered, I'll show you how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This is real dirty, but if you're sure they're in the format they're in, you could throw some perl together to parse it... something like

```
for (<STDIN>) {
  if (/<key>([^<]*)</) { print $1 . " : "; }
  if (/<string>([^<]*)</) { print $1 . "\n"; }
}
```

that may not be perfect, but close to accomplishing what you're looking for. I'm sure there is probably some perl module that will parse XML for you, too, but for such a non-complex schema, I think you'll be ok without it.

Comment: how can i modify this in such a way that it does not take attributes other than name and id into consideration??

Comment: the xml document seems to be pretty unstructured :) Try changing it to  <entry><key>NAME</key><value>Mr Jones</value></entry> for example. That way it's much easier to process it

Comment: I agree, the XML is badly structured. If you are able to change it, you might as well do it properly: <entry><id>51</id><name>Mr. Jones</name></entry>

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the file foo.bar containing the following text:

```
<key>Name</key>
<string>Mr Jones</string>
<key>ID</key>
<string>51</string>
<key>Len</key>
<string>53151334</string>
```

something like this will work:

```
$ awk -F '[<>]' '{if (FNR%2==1) {printf "%s: ",$3} else {print $3}}' foo.bar
Name: Mr Jones
ID: 51
Len: 53151334
```

If it's not entirely what you're wanting, shoe-horn it further to meet your specific requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't include the separator line because I wasn't sure if you wanted it or it was just an artifact of using `grep`.  It's easy enough to add it in:

```
find -name "list.xml" | xargs awk  -F '[<>]' -f xml.awk < in.dat
```

And the contents of `xml.awk`:

```
$2 != "string" { K=$3 }
$2 == "string" { if ((K == "Name") || (K == "ID")) print K ": " $3 }
```